# Redirecionar sem alterar a URL

Tags: php

Não sei se consegui ser claro no meu título, mas tenho um sistema multitenancy e para cada um será criado um subdomínio. Ex.:

> http://inquilino1.site.com.br

Dentro desse subdomínio conterá o acesso ao sistema que está localizado na pasta raiz do servidor. Tem como dentro do subdomínio direcionar para o sistema na pasta raiz, mas sem perder a referência? Ou seja, mesmo acessando de dentro do subdomínio e sendo redirecionado para a pasta raiz, o sistema aparecer como se estivesse dentro do subdomínio?

Perdoem-me se não consegui ser muito claro.

Comment: Seria possível exemplificar?

Comment: Olá Maurício. Cada inquilino terá um subdomínio, só que o sistema está na pasta raiz. Em cada subdomínio conterá um arquivo que fará a conexão e o direcionamento para o sistema. O problema é que quando é direcionado para o sistema, ele saí do subdomínio e o que queremos é que mesmo indo para o sistema, no navegador continue aparecendo o endereço do subdomínio e não do sistema. Em outras palavras, redirecionar sem alterar a url.

Comment: Se você redireciona não tem como exceto de você tiver um servidor de proxy reverso tipo nginx que vai Ser o intermediario. Ou seja ele recebe a requisicao envia para o original é quando receber o retorno devolve a quem requisitou mantendo no navegador a requisicao original

Comment: Se for Apache http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/